How to bypass a proxy using urllib3 (boto3 s3)
I am trying to bypass a proxy using boto3 s3 get_object.
I know boto3 uses urllib3 exclusively under the hood but post 2022 there is no support for the no_proxy env variable.
How can I bypass a proxy then?
I wasn't able to find any resources on how to bypass a proxy and no_proxy is not supported as part of the client config of boto3.
